# Prevent custom command to run at terminal startup

Tags: linux, terminal, mate

I am on `Debian Jessie` with `Mate` (v1.8.1) desktop environment.

I have installed `byobu` and wanted to launch it every time I open a terminal so I went into the profile preferences, checked *Run a custom command instead of my shell* and add the following command:
`/usr/bin/byobu`

It worked fine but I had the annoying startup message from `byobu` on each opening so I tried to mask the output by changing naively the command to:
`/usr/bin/byobu > /dev/null`

And here was my mistake... Now every time I launch a terminal it is closed immediately : I have no longer access to my profile preferences to edit the command.
I do have access to `Xterm` though (i.e. I have a way to execute command lines).

- How can I prevent the custom command to run on terminal launch ?
- Where is stored the `mate-terminal` config file ? (so I can maybe manually removed the profile preferences)

P.S. I am aware of the `--profile=PROFILE_NAME` option of `mate-terminal` that I could launch from `Xterm`, unfortunately I have only one profile : the corrupted one.
I cannot find an option to launch `mate-terminal` with no preferences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the location of terminal profile configuration file so here is what I did:

- install `dconf` (GUI editor for desktop environment settings)
- launch `dconf-editor`
- Go to org > mate > terminal > profiles > profile0
- edit the key "custom command" (set it to empty)

After that I was able to launch the terminal without executing my custom command and had access to profile preferences again.